# Of what structure does the body consist in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        MapView(coordinate: landmark.locationCoordinate)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
            .frame(height: 300)
        
        CircleImage(image: landmark.image)
            .offset(y: -130)
            .padding(.bottom, -130)
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(landmark.name)
                    .font(.title)
                FavoriteButton(isSet: $modelData.landmarks[landmarkIndex].isFavorite)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text(landmark.park)
                Spacer()
                Text(landmark.state)
            }
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            
            Divider()
            
            Text("About \(landmark.name)")
                .font(.title2)
            Text(landmark.description)
        }
        .padding()
    }
    .navigationTitle(landmark.name)
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
}
```

Hi. I'm totally new to Swift, so I have some difficult to understand some code's structure. The code above is an example from SwiftUi tutorial.

How is it possible to list structures just into curly braces? What are curly braces for? Are those closures and return some structures' instances in those closures? Only thing I can understand is calling methods parts.
Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is that the body function of a SwiftUI View is defined to be a thing called a "function builder" https://forums.swift.org/t/function-builders/25167. The idea is allow SwiftUI to be a Domain-specific language within Swift. You can make your own DSL's using function builders, which are (were) also known as "result builders".

For example, from the 'function builder' Swift language proposal, this is the kind of idea for function builders:

```
func div(@HTMLBuilder makeChildren: () -> [HTML]) -> HTMLNode { ... }

div {
  if useChapterTitles {
    h1("1. Loomings.")
  }
  p {
    "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago"
  }
  p {
    "There is now your insular city"
  }
}
```

The other magic is Swift's "trailing closure syntax" which is also used to make lots of API feel more like control flow, or at least part of the language.

Comment: Is the body of SwiftUI a function? It seems to be an opaque type variable that conforms View.

Comment: The body isn't a function.  If you look at the header, "public protocol View" has "body" property marked with @ViewBuilder, and ViewBuilder is a struct marked @_functionBuilder - these "function builder" things are syntactic sugar that let us build domain-specific languages in Swift. You can make your own function builder: Declare a struct, mark it as @_functionBuilder. Add a static method "buildBlock", that takes at least one argument. This argument will be what is inside the braces when the function builder is called.